# serverless-offline optional path parameter

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, serverless-framework-offline

I'm trying to set up a GET request with an optional parameter but I get an error when I call the url **locally** without the optional parameter. It works fine online on lambda though.
What did I do wrong?

I'm using serverless version 1.24.1 with the serverless-offline plugin version 3.16.0

here is my request definition in **serverless.yml**:

```
functions:
getitems:
    handler: lambda.handler
    events:
      - http:
            path: item/store/{storeid}/{itemstatus}
            method: get
            cors: true
            request:
                parameters:
                  paths:
                    storeid: true
                    itemstatus: false
```

this url works:

```
http://localhost:3000/item/store/123456/used
```

this don't

```
http://localhost:3000/item/store/123456
```

and gives me this output

```
{
   statusCode: 404,
   error: "Serverless-offline: route not found.",
   currentRoute: "get - /item/store/123456",
   existingRoutes: [
       "get - item/store/{storeid}/{itemstatus}"
   ]
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately Chen Dachao's answer fails with:

> An error occurred: ApiGatewayResourceExperimentExperimentVarPsizeVar -
>   Resource's path part only allow a-zA-Z0-9._- and curly braces at the
>   beginning and the end.

The current workaround to this is adding http handlers for each 'optional' variable in the path like so:

```
functions:
  getitems:
    handler: lambda.handler
      events:
        - http:
            path: item/store/{storeid}
            method: get
            cors: true
            request:
              parameter:
                storeid: true
        - http:
            path: item/store/{storeid}/{itemstaus}
            method: get
            cors: true
            request:
              parameter:
                storeid: true
                itemstatus: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "?" after the params can make it work.

```
functions:
  getitems:
  handler: lambda.handler
  events:
    - http:
        path: item/store/{storeid}/{itemstatus?}
        method: get
        cors: true
```

Comment: This only worked for 1 optional path param

Answer (score 0):

If you want `itemstatus` to be optional then you must set it to false in your serverless request definition like so:

```
- http:
            path: item/store/{storeid}/{itemstaus}
            method: get
            cors: true
            request:
              parameter:
                storeid: true
                itemstatus: false
```

Comment: Error on deployment: Resource's path part only allow a-zA-Z0-9._- and curly braces at the beginning and the end. (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following option and it worked with and without the parameters

```
- http:
      path: auth/{role?}
      method: get
      request:
          parameter:
              paths:
                  role: false
```